# Can't read bar code 128 in mobile

Tags: ios, swift3

I got a code for reading barcode trough phone camera, but it cannot recognize code-128. Anyone knows whats wrong with the code?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

var cameraView: CameraView!
let session = AVCaptureSession()
let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: AVCaptureSession.self.description(), attributes: [], target: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

//*** capture initialization / configuring the session to recognize two barcode types ***

```
        session.beginConfiguration()

    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if (videoDevice != nil) {
        let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)

        if (videoDeviceInput != nil) {
            if (session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)) {
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
            }
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (session.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            session.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [
                AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
            ]

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        }
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()

    cameraView.layer.session = session
    cameraView.layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

end view controller class

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if (metadataObjects.count > 0 && metadataObjects.first is AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) {
        let scan = metadataObjects.first as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Barcode Scanned", message: scan.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: is that a real question, I mean, seriously?!

Comment: @holex if you see "?", its basically a question mark. Newbie here! I wonder if you know 1+1 when you were born. chow

Comment: it is not about _not knowing_ something, because you could google for it anytime... it is about _not having a single clue about what is black and white_, so you can't really google for it, because you don't seem to understand a single line of the code you are working with – that where my initial surprised question came from.

Comment: @holex Now I wonder if you understand the meaning of newbie. LOL

Comment: no one is arrogant here – but stating the truth could hurt.

Comment: stating the truth might hurt, you seem hurt HAHAHA

Comment: yeah... tell me more about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring the camera to scan ***Ean13*** and ***QR*** codes. You just need to replace these lines:

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [
            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
        ]
```

with these:

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code
        ]
```